# Calling MASM32 procedure from .c

Tags: c, masm32

I am using visual studio at the moment. I need to build a win32 application and need to call a procedure from a C function but I am always getting a build error:

Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I have reduced everything down to a simple main function and simple .asm file with one procedure and I am still getting the same build (or rather link) error. I'm at a loss.

Both are using the cdecl convention.

The MASM32 code (in its own .asm file):

```
.MODEL FLAT, C
.DATA              

.CODE      

PUBLIC memory_address

memory_address PROC 

    mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp] 

    ret

memory_address ENDP

END
```

It assembles fine. The .c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern int memory_address(int* ptr);

void main()
{
    int *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    memory_address(ptr);

    while (1) {}

    return;
}
```

No idea why this is happening. I have been using MASM happily for 64bit application for about a year or so with no problems. But I have to make a 32bit application I am having no luck calling the MASM32 proc memory_address().

I hasten to add I know how to do this in NASM for 32 bit applications and I know how to do it for 64bit applications using MASM. This is strictly a MASM32 issue. Any suggestions would be great - but only for MASM32. Thanks.

Comment: I know you want answers for MASM32, but how did you do this in NASM? Could you show that too? Just edit your question to show the NASM code that worked.

Comment: Try adding a leading underscore to the name of the masm procedure?

Comment: Also, doesn't it mention the name it tries to find, right before the error you quoted?

Comment: To see which name is given to `memory_address`, dump the object file, e.g. with DUMPBIN. And, as @anatolyg says, it could well be that C expects a leading underscore. Then you should add that in your `.asm` file. 64 bit does not expect underscores, AFAIK.

Comment: anatolyg - tried this before but of course the linker just adds another underscore to the token.Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _memory_address referenced in function _main

Comment: I believe @anatolyg meant that you should add a leading underscore to the PUBLIC, PROC and ENDP in the asm file.  Your comment makes it sound like you tried to change the .c file.  There is also the question of exactly which compiler you are using to compile the C code.  If (for whatever reason) VS is using the c++ compiler instead of the C compiler, you will want to use `extern "C"` for your function prototype instead of just `extern`.

Comment: No did all that. And the C++ compiler treats .c files as C compilations - the "C" qualifier is a syntax error in C as it is when compiling .c files in VS.

Comment: That narrows it down. Next you can try `dumpbin.exe ms.obj /symbols` (where ms.obj is your asm file's output) and look for memory_address. If that doesn't clarify, you can also try dumpbin against your c program's output file (you might need to redirect the output to a file).  Look for memory_address here.  If everything still looks right, look at the VS build log for your project. You want to find where it is calling link.exe and make sure the obj file for your asm is listed. Failing all that, paste the 2 memory_address symbols and the link line in your question. NB check file datetimes!

Comment: Thanks David. Ill give it a try later. Failing that I may just relent and inline in C wrapper functions. I was hoping for an easy 64 to 32but port. But VS while powerful has slowly become an over-engineered bloat - a bit like C++ ;)

Comment: @cdcdcd It's easy to blame your tools. However, when 1 year later you look again at your situation, you will remember something like "I failed to do the porting properly because VS is such a complicated mess", while the truth is "I failed to do the porting properly because I was too lazy".

Comment: Thanks anatolyg for that rather condescending comment - it really helped me out. As I said VS is a very nice IDE the problem is that as technologies diverge it gets bloated trying to cater as an all encompassing integrated system.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your asm module as DLL.

Its easy to use STDCALL for all this,
so instead:

```
.MODEL FLAT, C
```

you can use:

```
.model flat, stdcall
```

simply create additional to your yourmodule.asm
a ***yourmodule.def*** file.
Within that place these lines:

```
LIBRARY "yourmodule.dll"
EXPORTS memory_address
```

then use:
ml.exe /c /coff yourmodule.asm
Link.exe /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /DLL /DEF:yourmodule.def yourmodule.obj

In your C++ application then remove:

```
extern int memory_address(int* ptr);
```

and add instead:

```
typedef void*(__stdcall *PTRmemory_address)(int*);
extern PTRmemory_address    memory_address = NULL; // init as "NOT PRESENT"

HMODULE yourmoduleHMODULE;
yourmoduleHMODULE = GetModuleHandleA("yourmodule.dll"); // ensure valid file path!
if (!yourmoduleHMODULE)
    yourmoduleHMODULE = LoadLibraryA("yourmodule.dll"); // ensure valid file path!

if (yourmoduleHMODULE)
{
    memory_address = (PTRmemory_address)GetProcAddress(yourmoduleHMODULE, "memory_address");
    if (!memory_address)
    { 
        printf("\n  Cannot Find function memory_address in yourmodule.dll");
        exit(1);  // exit application when function in DLL not found
    }
}    
else
{
    printf("\n  yourmodule.dll not found");
    exit(1); // exit application when DLL not found
}
```

calling your function:

```
int *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

if (memory_address)  // ensure, that your function is present
  memory_address(ptr);
else 
  printf("\n error");

    // ....
```